# How to show keytip in Word custom xml ribbon menu?

Tags: xml, vba, ms-word, ribbon

I built a custom ribbon in Word. Keytips are fine for the custom tab and the first-level buttons in the tab.

I would like keytips on my menu buttons. I've been searching for an answer for some time.

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<ribbon>
<tabs>
  <tab id="customTab" label="Plain English" keytip="X" >
    <group id="Interface" label="Interface with Excel" >

        <menu id="Menu1" label="Copy Exercises" size="large" imageMso="Paste" keytip="E" >
        <button id="Btn1" label="Dict1" imageMso="OutlineDemote" onAction="pasteDictation1" keytip="D1" />
        <button id="Btn2" label="Dict2" imageMso="OutlineDemote" onAction="pasteDictation2" keytip="D2" />
        <button id="Btn3" label="Voice" imageMso="OutlineDemote" onAction="pasteVoice" keytip="V" />
        <button id="Btn4" label="FITB" imageMso="OutlineDemote" onAction="pasteFITB" keytip="F1" />
        <button id="Btn5" label="FITB2" imageMso="OutlineDemote" onAction="pasteFITB2" keytip="F2" />
        <button id="Btn6" label="MATCH" imageMso="OutlineDemote" onAction="pasteMatch" keytip="M" />

    </menu >

        <menu id="Menu2" label="Build links" size="large" imageMso="EditLinks" keytip="B" >
        <button id="build1" label="Find strings" imageMso="FindDialog" onAction="linkHistory1" keytip="F" />
        <button id="build2" label="Build links" imageMso="EditLinks" onAction="linkHistory2" keytip="B" />
    </menu >


        <menu id="Menu3" label="Copy to Excel" size="large" imageMso="CopyToPersonalCalendar" keytip="C" >
        <button id="cop1" label="First copy" imageMso="_1" onAction="firstCopy" keytip="1" />
        <button id="cop2" label="Second copy" imageMso="_2" onAction="secondCopy" keytip="2" />
    </menu >

      <button id="jrh" visible="true" size="large" 
              label="JR Highlights" keytip="H" 
              onAction="findReplace2"                                       
        imageMso="TextHighlightColorPicker"/>



    </group>
    <group id="Links" label="Links" >

      <menu id="Menu4" label="Internal Links" size="large" imageMso="ImportTextFile" keytip="L" >
        <button id="il1" label="Lessons" imageMso="OutlineDemote" onAction="linkLessons" keytip="d" />
        <!--button id="il2" label="Current Lesson" imageMso="OutlineDemote" onAction="linkCurrentLesson" keytip="b" />
        <button id="il3" label="Expressions" imageMso="OutlineDemote" onAction="linkExpressions" keytip="c" />
        <button id="il4" label="Current Expression" imageMso="OutlineDemote" onAction="linkCurrentExpression" keytip="d" />             
        <button id="il5" label="Videos" imageMso="OutlineDemote" onAction="linkVideos" keytip="e" />
        <button id="il9" label="Current Video" imageMso="OutlineDemote" onAction="linkCurrentVideo" keytip="f" /> 
        <button id="il6" label="Lingo" imageMso="OutlineDemote" onAction="linkLingo" keytip="g" />
        <button id="il7" label="Current Lingo" imageMso="OutlineDemote" onAction="linkCurrentLingo" keytip="h" />
        <button id="il8" label="Number" imageMso="OutlineDemote" onAction="linkNumber" keytip="i" /-->
    </menu >


      <button id="lin2" visible="true" size="large" 
              label="External Link" keytip="X" 
              onAction="linkExternal"                               
        imageMso="ExportTextFile"/>

    </group>

  </tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

And images of the buttons and menus:

[image: keytips]

[image: menu]

Comment: What's the purpose of your key tip ... to provide more information than the label gives? Maybe you should consider SuperTip instead. Personally and no offense meant, but I think the E B C H L X labels look awful.

Comment: @RichMichaels - that is not the purpose of keytips. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbonbutton.keytip?view=vsto-2017)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a vague recollection that Keytips aren't used for menu items, but I can't confirm that from the documentation I have to hand. However, if you look at the built-in menus the keytips correspond to the accelerator key for the menu item.

[image]

Based on that I would try adding accelerator keys to your menu items

```
<button id="cop1" label="&amp;First copy" imageMso="_1" onAction="firstCopy" />
<button id="cop2" label="&amp;Second copy" imageMso="_2" onAction="secondCopy" />
```

Comment: Hi Timothy, thanks for your reply. I don't quite understand what you mean, sorry! What's the difference between an accelerator key and a keytip? The fact that the built-in menus have keytips makes me think I should be able to add them to mine. In your example xml I can only see keytips in your buttons as I already have in mine.

Comment: @kwibbler - accelerator key = shortcut key. It displays as an underlined character on the menu and is assigned by the “&amp;” in the label text, as shown in my example xml.